# Query by name in a big database using match against

Tags: mysql

I've tried to come up with a solution by myself and so far I had no success

There's this big database with customers names and address, it has about 400kk rows, the problem is that it takes an enormous amount of time to return some results ( about 10 minutes )

Table layout:

| COLUMN | TYPE | INDEX |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CUSTOMER_ID | bigint |  |
| NAME | varchar(100) | index FULLTEXT |
| CITY_NUMBER | int | index |

Supposed I want to fetch the **customer_id** from the customer *FIRST SECOND*, he lives in the city_number *9999* and I only want the ones that start with "*FIRST*" ( because otherwise is going to return people called "THIRD SECOND FIRST" and so on ), customers called FIRST SECOND THIRD should match as well, but not FIRST THIRD FORTH ( must contain all words )

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID 
FROM `table` 
WHERE match(NAME) AGAINST('+FIRST +SECOND' in boolean mode) 
AND CITY_NUMBER = '99999' 
AND NAME like "FIRST %"
```

I tried to separate customers from their address and use JOIN but it took even longer to query.

Is there something I'm missing ? Because mysql is ignoring the index.

Comment: FTS is not suitable for this kind of searching.

Comment: *fetch the customer_id from the customer FIRST SECOND* Does `'FIRST SECOND'` is complete value to be found? Or `'FIRST SECOND THIRD'` matches too? and `'FIRST FORTH SECOND THIRD'`?

Comment: good point... customers called FIRST SECOND THIRD should match as well... but not FIRST THIRD FORTH ( must contain all words )

Comment: *but not FIRST THIRD FORTH ( must contain all words )* What about `'FIRST FORTH SECOND THIRD'`? both words are present, FIRST starts...

Comment: yep, that one matches too... needs to start with FIRST tho

Comment: Does the words matches must be separate words? I.e. `'FIRSTWORD SECOND'` or `'FIRST NOTSECOND'` does not match, is it?

Comment: it does not match because its gonna be a completely different client, like, `ALEX ANDER JOSE` and `ALEXANDER JOSE` same letters but 2 different people

Answer (score 0):

400K records is hardly "big". Databases can generally work with millions before breaking a sweat. Like Akina says, the full text search is suboptimal here. If you already know the city number, then you can pass it (as an integer) and ditch `MATCH`:

```
SELECT `customer_id`, `name` 
  FROM `table`
 WHERE `city_number` = 99999 and `name` LIKE 'FIRST%SECOND'
```

So long as `city_number` has a decent index, the result should be almost instantaneous.

Comment: I updated the question, it should be 400kk, but the thing is, why is it ignoring both indexes ?